# Android, String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, mysql, string, json

I want to access Android apps through Web-Service.
In the web service the new registration is performed.
In the android apps, the xml file for the new registration is made. 
The data is saved successfully in SQL server database and it save properly by web service and return data get in jason string.

But when string is converted to JSONObject, it give me error like this:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**LoginActivity**

```java
package com.example.shy.wel.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.shy.wel.LoadingActivity;
import com.example.shy.wel.MainActivity;
import com.example.shy.wel.R;
import com.example.shy.wel.app.AppConfig;
import com.example.shy.wel.app.AppController;
import com.example.shy.wel.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.example.shy.wel.helper.SessionManager;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Intent loading = new Intent(this, LoadingActivity.class);
        startActivity(loading);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**My logcat**

```
04-22 13:41:55.092 14473-14521/com.example.shy.wel E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7facc84b6ad0
04-22 13:41:55.117 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-22 13:41:55.117 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-22 13:41:55.117 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.example.shy.wel.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:129)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.example.shy.wel.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:120)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
04-22 13:41:55.118 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-22 13:41:55.119 14473-14473/com.example.shy.wel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-22 13:41:55.123 1606-1779/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b10ec75 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@afd2b1e
04-22 13:41:55.174 14473-14521/com.example.shy.wel W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-22 13:41:55.174 14473-14521/com.example.shy.wel W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7facbe4a2500, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-22 13:41:58.629 14473-14521/com.example.shy.wel E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7facc84b6c90
```

Comment: the data returned by your web service is not valid, try to validate it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your returned string is `<br` which is not valid JSON. The String has to be properly formatted JSON for it to successfully be converted to a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. The problem may be in JSON. Try the generated JSON on this page [JSON Formatter and Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is a common problem, if you check the JSONObject Constructor says:

```
Parameters:
source - `A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).`
```

it means that probably is missing the braces... try to do:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{" + response + "}");
```

OR can be the opposite, it can have some lost chars around the string (debug it and check), in that case the solution would be:

```
new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Good luck =)